# Magento getChildHtml product_type_data

Tags: magento, templates, product

In Magento where can i edit the html that is output by the `product_type_data` the price find is what I want to edit

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
```

i tried editing the `price.phtml` but that didn't change anything.

/`app/design/frontend/default/THEME/template/catalog/product/price.phtml`

Answer (score 3):

You answer lies in:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml
```

Check to see if this file exists in your theme first.  If it does, congrats your ready to make some edits. However, it does not make sure you copy this file from base into your theme before making any edits.